# Blackberry twitter connect using oAuth and twitter API me library

Tags: twitter, blackberry

I'm building an application for BB to connect to twitter.
Does anyone know how to use "twitter api me library" to connect to twitter using oAuth (not xAuth), and give me an example working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read the project's wiki page. There are some good code snippets that may help you on this matter.

http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime

Regards,

Comment: That page just show how to login twitter using single access token, which not the one I want. I need to login to twitter using username and password with oAuth

Comment: Taken from http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime - "From August 16th, 2010, the only method to authenticate with Twitter API is via xAuth"

Comment: I dont think xAuth is the only way to connect to Twitter, because my friend developed Android application, and still can use oAuth to post a tweet few days ago